# Threads based socket communication - Python 3.3.3

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.3

I have no idea how can I put threads to my socket program. I need your help. I made simple socket script, but then I got stuck. Code is following:

```
 import socket,pickle,time,sys
 import threading 

 def receive():
    addr = (host,port)
    ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ss.bind(addr)
    ss.listen(5)
    print('Server is listening')
    clsocket, claddr = ss.accept()
    while 1:
        data = clsocket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            data = pickle.loads(data) # Or json.loads(data)
            print("receive data: ", data)
            clsocket.send(mdata)
    clsocket.close()
    ss.close()

 def send():
    addr = (host,port)
    ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect(addr)
    clientsocket.send(mdata)
    print('sended data: ',pickle.loads(mdata))
    data = clientsocket.recv(buf)
    data = pickle.loads(data)
    print("prijate data: ",data)
    ss.close()

 host = 'localhost'
 port=1234
 buf = 1024

 mdata = ['dns','dhcp','firewall']
 mdata = pickle.dumps(mdata)

 receive()
 time.sleep(1)
 send()
```

I wanna make peer-to-peer script. This script will be used by three or more computers. This computers should exchange data at any moment, so they should be ready anytime. The main point is, that receive() function will be run always, something like backround thread. Other thread should process received data. Then the receive() thread should be run again, or continue. I know there is needed interuption, and multitasking. I am new one in python, and threads too. I have read few documents, but I found nothing including my problem. I am using Python 3.3.3.

Any advices? or hint?

Best Regards

Jozef